# Where is the HOST header taken from when relative requests are made?

Tags: html, http, httprequest, fiddler

According to the [SPEC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2) :

> The most common form of Request-URI is that used to identify a
>   resource on an origin server or gateway. In this case the absolute
>   path of the URI MUST be transmitted  as
>   the Request-URI, and the network location of the URI (authority) **MUST**
>   be transmitted in a **Host** header field.
>   For example, a client wishing
>   to retrieve the resource above directly from the origin server would
>   create a TCP connection to port 80 of the host "www.w3.org" and send
>   the lines:
>
> ```
>    GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
>    Host: www.w3.org
> ```

So when a user make this request , it gets a response.

Ok now that this cycle is *over(!)* - a user clicks on a `<a href="/help">Help</a>` link.

- Notice that the address is relative.
- Also notice - the `form` does *not*(!) has  an `action` with the base url ("www.w3.org/help") .

[Example (look in the iframe's view source)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit) :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uChSE6Q.png]

- Also notice - that there is no `<base>` tag which represents the base url

Ok. so what is the question ?

**Question**

If a user  clicks on the hyperlink , how does the browser knows the `host` value to go to ? AFAIK it is not from the address bar url .

I know that document.location contains all the information but still - I dont think `JS` is involved here.

Knowing that the previous cycle (request) is over ( the first request) - Where does the `host` header value is taken from when relative requests are  now made ?

A **SPEC** reference would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

[I've been investigating it](http://jsbin.com/yarijo/1/edit?html,output) a bit with Fiddler :

So for this html :

```
<body>
  <a href="/GetSomething"> Click me</a>
</body>
```

Fiddler show this result :

```
GET http://null.jsbin.com/GetSomething HTTP/1.1
Host: null.jsbin.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://null.jsbin.com/runner
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.474312101.1437654587; _gat=1; jsbin=s%3A...
```

The URL is the full URL ( obviously) :

```
http://null.jsbin.com/GetSomething
```

It might be very simple question to ask , but still - where does it take the BASE url from ? (Javascript ( document.location?) ? address bar url ? some internal storage inside the browser?)

Comment: _"AFAIK it is not from the address bar url"_ - you assume this is true because...

Comment: Ah, because in this case the browser URL is not the url of the page with the link, due to the iframe

Comment: The browser just has to keep track of which file was downloaded from which URL - as simple as that.

Comment: @Eric I don't think so. look here at SO's form. there is no target url .http://i.imgur.com/3NkbLi4.png nor base tag nor iframe usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE

"
12.4.1 Resolving relative URIs

User agents must calculate the base URI for resolving relative URIs according to [[RFC1808]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1808), section 3. The following describes how [[RFC1808]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1808) applies specifically to HTML.

User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following precedences (highest priority to lowest):

1. The base URI is set by the BASE element.
2. The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol
   interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [[RFC2616]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC2616)).

> 3. By default, the base URI is that of the current document. Not all
>      HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may
>      appear in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML
>      documents are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and
>      rely on a default base URI.

"

`www.anotherebsite.com/action_page.php` defined in `<a href=""/>` is known as a relative link to the browser.
So on clicking the browser doesn't update the host it's sending the request.

But `http://www.anotherebsite.com/action_page.php` is a remote address for browser and updates the host on click and navigate client to the remote address.

User agent is the browser or the application that connects to the server to send and receive requests from client side. Example of user agents are browsers like Firefox,IE,Chrome. 
Each time when a user agent/browser want a specific page to be displayed it send request to the server asking for that content. and the server responds the way it want to(normally). The server than sends the requested data as text to the ip of the browser and is navigated to the client by routers and so on. On receiving text the browser changes markups according to HTML for the user interface.

Browsers are designed to have local storage spaces caches that stores the links you visit, information and other data like form data, window content, passwords and history etc.

```
GET http://null.jsbin.com/GetSomething HTTP/1.1
Host: null.jsbin.com
```

In here the browser is requesting the host(null.jsbin.com) to sent (GetSomething)
The data is sent to "null.jsbin.com" asking for "GetSomething"

Server identifies the browser through following

- Cookies (stored on the client side, that could be retrieved later)
- IP address
- Browser fingerprinting

here's a way to check what data actually can be retrieved from your browser by web servers https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes. that data can be used for browser fingerprinting to identify the browsers by servers.

As the network model says a persistent (connection may not be real persistent as the page has already loaded, but as ip addresses and other identifiers as mentioned above the server knows that its the same browser/user agent during the same session) connection is managed in between a client and server through session layer. The server knows its clients through the data that it takes while handshakes. and later it can know thorough instantiating a session id for each client and also through cookies the client could remember

Comment: You explain to me how and http works and sends  (which I already know). I asked merely about : **"where does it get the HOST header from , on a relative requests"**. the OSI model has nothing to do here.

Comment: @RoyiNamir added a paragraph to up removed model image. want to know more, happy to help here :)

Comment: It is not clear on what server you are talking about here. ("_The Server always tries the links as local if protocols_").When I click `<a>` - At THAT STAGE There is no server involved yet. but still it knows where to go in relative urls. So this answer still didnt answer the question. Also - I'm after a SPEC proof.

Comment: @RoyiNamir added references to up. :)

Comment: ooh. Thats what you want to know, So i am removing all other parts. :)

Comment: Im jsut asking to be sure

Comment: ya i am sure cos its the W3 recommended way of creating browses /user agents that are to be followed by everyone to maintain the international standard. and all the common browsers follow that rule.

Answer (score 1):

It's taken from the base URI of the document the form is contained in.

(BTW: you're looking at an absolute spec; the relevant one is RFC 7230).

Comment: Do you mean from the address bar url ?

Comment: The address bar is a user interface element, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: So i guess i don't understand your answer . Where the host address is taken when clicking relative links ? Don't forget that a document  doesn't has to have a form

Comment: The User Agent knows where it loaded the document from, and that, in general, is the base URI. The gory details about that should be in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: But I don't understand : When I request `A.com` , and then got response , this cycle of reuest<->response is finished! no memory to any of previous request is kept anywhere. So now if I click on a `<a href="/aboutUs">` , Where does the base URI is taken from ? (I remind you that the previous request is finished already.I'll be happy for a reference.

Comment: The request is finished, but that doesn't mean the User Agent can not remember that.

Comment: Do you have any reference to that ? Because as far as i remember - useragent contains information about browser , lang , OS .... But not host name

Comment: User-Agent == "client" or "browser", not the request header field

Comment: May I ask for any documentation reference ?